# mySQL-query from Microsoft Access VBA fails if not interactive?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, ms-access, odbc

I'm fighting with a VBA non-interactive problem that really bugs me: I have a pass-through query to a mysql database, which works well if double-clicked by the user. But it fails if called from VBA automation session (called from excel) if no interaction was done first. Most strange: it works from VBA *after* clicking it on the GUI for a while (odbc mysql connection timeout possibly).

The passthrough-query has it's password in the DSN and in the connection string (to sort out problems with the store). The behavior is the same with a linked table.

Problematic VBA code called looks like this:

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "INSERT INTO [SomeLocalTable] (id) SELECT id FROM [somePassThroughOrLinkedMySQLTable]"
```

The error is a generic odbc connection failure 80004005.

While this type of query works all the time:

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Open ("Driver=MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver;SERVER=myserver;UID=user;DATABASE={db};PORT=3306;DFLT_BIGINT_BIND_STR=1;PWD=secret")
```

Can I "initialize" the passthrough query like the UI does to make it work? Or can I use the second type of query to insert into a local MS Access table?

Environment: Win8-64bit, Office2013, mysql-odbc-5.2w

Comment: Hey, I did not find this article yet. Even though I think it does not apply, as the credentials are already stored in the connection string, I will try it, first. Stay tuned...

Comment: Nope, won't help: Like suggested there I executed 'CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("SELECT * FROM [ODBC;DSN=vTiger;Driver=MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver;SERVER=myserver;UID=table;DATABASE={db};PORT=3306;DFLT_BIGINT_BIND_STR=1;PWD=secret].mysqlTable WHERE FALSE")' - it fails with the same error if (and only if) the connection was not established with the GUI before.

Comment: it was the same as the table name that's why I confused it for the post - changed it to "user"

Comment: wild guesses are welcome as well ;)

Comment: Can you create and run an Append query from the Access UI (not from VBA) with the same statement?

Comment: You get the same error both when referring to a pass-through query and when referring to a linked table?

Comment: If you open the db file in an Access session and run the following command in the Immediate window, replacing "LinkedMySqlTable" with the name of one of your links, do you see UID and PWD values included in the connection string? `Debug.Print CurrentDb.TableDefs("LinkedMySqlTable").Connect`

Comment: @HansUp will test that tomorrow...

Comment: @HansUp: yes, uid and pwd are printed

Comment: @Christian So to be clear, you have your Access pass through query, but are wanting to call it externally from Excel, could you explain why it's not all been carried out in Access?

Comment: That's true, Matt. It is a more complex query that I'm calling from excel. One of the sources for these queries is a mysql table. And I need Excel for the pretty diagrams :)

Comment: @Christian So the more complex query is separate to the issue mentioned in the question, and the question only refers to appending data into an access table from a MySQL query. But it is neater and makes more sense to call the whole process from Excel?

Comment: @Matt: exactly (I narrowed it down this way) - Excel is just the cause for calling it without Access UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is happening because you are referring to the Access database as an external ADODB data source, instead I would use an instance of Access in order to run the query via DAO.  The sample sub below creates an invisible instance of Access and executes the query, and then quits once finished. I've used late binding in this example with DAO version 3.6 so you may need to amend that bit slightly or use early binding:

```
Sub ExecPassThru()

Dim acApp As Object
Dim acDb As Object

    Set acApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    Set acDb = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.36") 'May need slight alteration
    acApp.OpenCurrentDatabase ("C:\db1.mdb") 'Amend as required

    Set acDb = acApp.CurrentDb

    acDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [SomeLocalTable] (id) SELECT id FROM [somePassThroughOrLinkedMySQLTable]"

    acDb.Close
    acApp.Quit 2

End Sub
```

This was coded using Excel 2003 but should be easy enough to translate to later versions of office.

Comment: That's what I'm already doing from Excel. But the problem is reproducible with Access itself. Just executing the VBA code 'CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("SELECT * FROM [ODBC;DSN=vTiger;Driver=MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver;SERVER=myserver;UID=table;DATABASE={db};PORT=3306;DFLT_BIGINT_BIND_STR=1;‌​PWD=secret].mysqlTable WHERE FALSE")' in Access shows the same behavior.

Comment: @Christian CurrentProject.Connection still uses the ADODB string rather than DAO which is why I suggested this method. In access do you still get the error if you use **CurrentDb.Execute** rather than **CurrentProject.Connection.Execute**?

Comment: CurrentDb.Execute prints another error message: Runtime Error 3065: A select query could not be executed (translated from german). But: OpenRecordset works! So using DAO instead of ADODB seems to be solution. And it's enough to use it once, afterwards I can continue with ADODB. This is a real bug in Access isn't it?
Thanks a lot for solving this!

Comment: @Christian I thought it was an **Insert Into** rather than **Select** query, true enough for DAO that **Selects** can't be executed. Note: Unless you only want basic Access queries with no UDF's or other interaction etc, then ADODB is ok, but for more involved procedures within Access DAO is a safer bet. And as you say, once this bit is done you can continue the rest with ADODB, glad to help : )